# Devise, allowing users to change passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an application that has a custom registration controller, called users_controller, for devise because only Admin is able to create users.  I want to allow users to change their password by entering their old password and entering a new one and I found: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password but it does not give enough detail.

What do I need to put in my routes?

Where and what do I need to put in my views?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a devise model User, you can use this path to route to the change password page.

```
edit_user_registration_path
```

Just use this in your view as:

```
<%= link_to 'Change Password', edit_user_registration_path %>
```

This should do the trick, it works for me.

Answer (score 7):

I have found the soulution and have fixed this on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)

Comment: well.. would you share with a more specific link? But thanks im looking up there :)

Comment: @DavidMauricio This was for an older version of Devise.  The current version you can do something like ```@user.update_with_password(params[:user])```

Comment: Here's a link to the actual information: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password, its quite long else I'd copy it here verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough, tough. You'll have to add `attr_accessor :current_password` to the model, like explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421873/cant-update-user-attributes-rails-and-devise).