# Can't update user attributes - Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I am using Rails (3.0.9) with Devise (1.5.3) and I have an User model in which the attributes can't be updated for some reason I have no idea about.

The form for this User object has many attributes including those from devise: password and password_confirmation, for example.

When I submit the form I get this in the logger:

`WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password`

But when I add `current_password` to `attr_accessible` I get:

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError at /users
unknown attribute: current_password`

I am not very into Devise but I think current_password is just a virtual attribute. This error is very annoying, have you any idea on why this is happening? I am clueless.

By the way, my `Users::RegistrationsController#update` action:

```
def update
  logger.error "SALMONELLA " + self.resource.password.inspect

  self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)

  #params[:user].delete [:current_password]

  if resource.update_attributes(params[:user])
    Resque.enqueue(MdcUpdateUser, resource.id)
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
    respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
  end
end
```

I've tried using Devise's `update_without_password` and tried also deleting `current_password` from the `params[:user]` hash but had no success.

I appreciate any help you give me. Please ask for any more information if you think there is any information missing in this question.

Comment: Can you post your User model code and form code?

Answer (score 7):

Then you may have to also add `attr_accessor :current_password` to your model.  Also see the  [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) and [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1620) for further insight.