# Use a different view for devise default change password method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Ok first i ask on how to use devise "change password" for users. here (there is the GEMLIST)
[Send Password for devise in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464682/send-password-for-devise-in-ruby-on-rails)

I actually did it by adding.

```
<%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %>
```

Great this take me to a view that is generate by devise, (can i set a different view?) thats fine.. thats working..

But when i try to send the password to my email.. this is the error i got

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

Searching i found that adding this to environment.rb must solve the problem but it dosent.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

So what can i do? first to make the error dissapear, and the to assign my own view to that? is that posible?

**EDIT:** Ok this is working now, the problem was, i need to put config.action_mailer on development.rb in folder `config/environments`  thats all..

in the mail i got "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"

I i went there and change this address But the link to "change password" is looking for `¿localhost:3000?` i thinks depends on this `:host => 'localhost:3000'` .

But Do i Have to Go and modify the views inside the largest route

`var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise/.............` (im sure not)

How can i use my own views, im lost here.. =( (sorry as you can notice im a noob on rails)

Comment: did you restart server?

Comment: OK, you have [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464682/send-password-for-devise-in-ruby-on-rails/17465453?noredirect=1#comment25393742_17465453), You can answer your workaround and accept it then close this question

Comment: Yes i was about to do so... just Edit because i dont know how to use my own views for this.. Read the bottom of de Question just Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok If you just need 1 view.. try to read this may help

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You can create just the view you need, you dont need to pull a lot of views that may also overwrite yours or generate errors.

If your a noob in rails, this will be better friend..

Hope this helps, let me know! im glad to help